# Python - trying to unpack a list comprehension to understand it

Tags: python, list-comprehension

This is a basic question that I am trying to figure out but can't seem to. I have a list comprehension that works as expected (for Advent of Code). For my reference I am trying to unpack it.

```
raw_data = """
30373
25512
65332
33549
35390
"""

forest = [[int(x) for x in row] for row in raw_data.split()]
print(forest)
```

which outputs:
`[[3, 0, 3, 7, 3], [2, 5, 5, 1, 2], [6, 5, 3, 3, 2], [3, 3, 5, 4, 9], [3, 5, 3, 9, 0]]`

So I am trying to unpack it to better understand it but it's not working as I expect.

```
t = []
for row in raw_data.split():
    for x in row:
        t.append(int(x))

print(t)
```

which outputs:
`[3, 0, 3, 7, 3, 2, 5, 5, 1, 2, 6, 5, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 5, 4, 9, 3, 5, 3, 9, 0]`

Comment: Take a look at `for x in row` in that second snippet. What is `row` there? Do you want to iterate over it like that?

Comment: What is what you are expecting? That might help you to get better answers :).

Comment: What does success look like?  Are you expecting the result to be a list that looks like this: `[30373, 25512, ...]`?

Comment: I believe the output from the first snippet (`[[3, 0, 3, 7, 3], [2, 5, 5, 1, 2], [6, 5, 3, 3, 2], [3, 3, 5, 4, 9], [3, 5, 3, 9, 0]]`) is correct and expected, per "I have a list comprehension that works as expected". OP is trying to convert that into a loop.

Comment: yes sorry if I was unclear; expected results is from the original output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
t = []
for row in raw_data.split():
    r = []
    for x in row:
        r.append(int(x))
    t.append(r)
```

print(t)